# Enabling Impersonation in IIS 7.5 via Powershell

Tags: security, iis, powershell, iis-7.5, impersonation

I hope someone can help, I am trying to enable enable "ASP.Net Impersonation" under the Authenticatuin section in IIS7, I have enabled other sections using the following command:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty `
    -filter /system.WebServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication `
    -name enabled `
    -value true `
    -location $SiteName
```

But I cannot find a similar command for setting up ASP.net Impersonation, I am guessing it has something to do with being ASP.net not IIS.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty `
    -Filter system.web/identity `
    -Name impersonate `
    -Value True `
    -Location $SiteName
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work on a desktop where ServerManager couldn't be loaded, but this approach works:
https://github.com/jefflomax/configure-iis-webapps-powershell

Comment: UserName and Password attributes ?

Comment: -PSPath instead of -Location ?

Answer (score 3):

Use -PSPath instead of -Location.

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -filter /system.web/identity -name impersonate -value true -PSPath 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\WebApp'
```

Comment: Thank you!! -Location was killing me