# Enabling ASP.NET Impersonation in IIS 10 via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, iis

I'm trying to enable ASP.NET Impersonation to Read/Write in Feature Delegation. I'm able to find other settings to set e.g. Authentication - Anonymous:

```
Set-WebConfiguration '/system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication' -Metadata "overrideMode" -Value "Allow" -PSPath "IIS:/"
```

Went through the applicationHost.config as well, no luck. Any help is appreciated!
I did check a similar post but such as this:
[Enabling Impersonation in IIS 7.5 via Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847647/enabling-impersonation-in-iis-7-5-via-powershell)
but it's not the right settings i'm after.

Comment: That's because you need to edit `identity` section in `machine.config` (you have multiple copies of that file on a machine), which isn't available via IIS/ASP.NET PowerShell cmdlets. People usually use direct XML editing.

Comment: Thanks for your input - I assume you are talking about "Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config"? I don't see anything related to impersonation though.

Comment: I already said it is `identity` tag, not `impersonation`.